# Disjoint disks covering of the unit disc

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $\{D_i\}_i\in \mathbb N $ be a countable collection of disjoint open disks, with radii of $\{r_i\}$, covering the open unit disk. It's easy to see that for every such cover, $ \underset {i\in \mathbb N} \Sigma  r_i^2 < \infty$ (because $ \underset {i\in \mathbb N} \Sigma  \pi r_i^2 = \pi$). I'm trying to show that for every $0<\alpha <2$ there is a disjoint cover as above, such that $ \underset {i\in \mathbb N} \Sigma  r_i^\alpha = \infty$. I tried  to build covers with radii of $\{\frac 1 {n^\varepsilon}\}$ with $\varepsilon \rightarrow \frac 1 2 ^+$, but it doesn't look like going to work, and I don't know another example of a sequences with that property  of being in $L^2$ and not being in $L^p$ for every $p<2$.

Comment: I doubt that you really mean “covering.” There’s no upper bound on the area of a covering of the open unit disk. On the other hand, no point on the boundary of an open disk can be covered by a disjoint open disk.

Comment: Why not, if all the disks are disjoint (mean, no overlap between any two disks)?

Comment: The last part is precisely **because** the are disjoint. Open means the boundary points are not covered. To cover one, it must be in the interior of another disk, but then that disk overlaps.

Comment: The area is unbounded because you can cover the unit disk with one disk and then make all the others radius $1$ as well. Just place them all side by side in a line.

Comment: I think what you may be trying to do is to “fill” the open disk with an infinite sequence of disjoint open disks. You want all disks contained in the unit disk, and you don’t mind if there are points of the unit disk that aren’t in any of the smaller disks as long as the set of such points has measure zero. Sorry to say I don’t know what this kind of object is called, I just don’t think it’s a cover.

Comment: I didn't think of the problem you described... but your last suggestion makes sense